# Using jQuery & Maximage2 as a simple slideshow

Tags: jquery, html, css, photos

I have been writing a very simple slide show pulling photos from flickr and looping though them using the arrow keys.

I got this working here (scroll with arrow keys): http://jsbin.com/esoveh/1/ but now that I try and add this to my octopress website I'm getting the pictures flowing behind the main section. I've tried to figure this out and all I can see is that the images have got a position: absolute set and a z-index while the rest of the content is not positioned absolutely, this may however be a false trail.

Any ideas would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've tried to give the div surrounding the elements a z-index of 100, and the pictures showed. So you can give that div (id="flicr") a style element, or add this in your css file:

```
#flicr
{
    z-index:100;
}
```